# Inverse Dictionary Lookup

Tags: string-manipulation, text, dictionary

Example: Using `WordDefinition`:

```
WordDefinition["surreptitious"]
```

> ```
> {"conducted with or marked by hidden aims or methods", "marked by \
> quiet and caution and secrecy; taking pains to avoid being observed"}
> ```

Let's say this appears in a crossword puzzle and I want to execute an inverse dictionary lookup for it. My current strategy turns up many related and good words.

```
Synonyms["secretive"]~Join~Synonyms["mysterious"]~Join~
 Synonyms["hidden"]~Join~Synonyms["unobservable"]
```

> ```
> {"close", "closelipped", "closemouthed", "tightlipped", "cryptic", \
> "cryptical", "deep", "inscrutable", "mystic", "mystical", \
> "mystifying", "occult", "orphic", "secret", "concealed", "obscure", \
> "out of sight", "secret"}
> ```

One way could be to execute `WordDefinition` and make key-value pairs for the entire dictionary and use that information to search for probable answers.

**Question**
How can I perform an inverse lookup using a phrase or a word. Is there a built-in method for it? Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Use cases**

1. Crossword puzzles
2. Alteration of articles
3. Automated summaries
4. Exclusion of selected words etc

etc.